ETC Billing Value in Deltek Vantagepoint - Unable to Extract
we're extracting project data from Vantagepoint into a data warehouse. We recently migrated from Vision to Vantagpoint, and as of that migration, we are unable to pull the ETC Billing value from a given plan. This value used to be in one the rp tables in Vision, however it looks like it is no longer stored in the database and the ETC calculation process might have changed? Can someone perhaps point me in the right direction to determine how this field is now calculated, and where it might be stored? Thank you in advance!
